# AJAX Возвращает всю страницу, а не то что нужно

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, response

**Отправка запроса AJAX**

```
function submitForm(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    const name = inp_name.value;

    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open("POST", `{{ route('admin.categories.store') }}`, true);

    xhr.responseType = 'text';
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-TOKEN', token);

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
            console.log(xhr.response);
        }
    }

    xhr.send(`name=${name}`);

}
```

**Принятие запроса на PHP**

```
public function store(CategoryRequest $request)
    {
        if ($request->ajax()) {
            return "AJAX";
        }
        return "HTTP";
    }
```

**То что возвращет**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**РЕШЕНИЕ ПРОБЛЕМЫ**

Добавил в заголовок ajax запроса:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", 'XMLHttpRequest');
```

Comment: А чего вы взяли что это не "то что нужно"?

Comment: Разве по логике return не завершает дальнейшую работу? Как мне вернуть только строку "AJAX"?

Comment: Вы не ответили на вопрос.

Comment: Хорошо, это то что нужно. Каким образом я могу сделать так, чтобы вернулась только строчка "AJAX"?

Comment: а чем fetch не угодил стандартный?